# Could geocodeAddressDictionary in iOS 9 be implemented different from iOS 8

Tags: ios, mapkit, geocoding

I am looping through a set of addresses and performing a geocode on each one.

```
    for aClient in passedPossible {

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        let checkAddress = [
            CNPostalAddressStreetKey:aClient[CNPostalAddressStreetKey]!,
            CNPostalAddressCityKey:aClient[CNPostalAddressCityKey]!,
            CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey:aClient[CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey]!,
            CNPostalAddressCountryKey:"Australia"
        ]


        geocoder.geocodeAddressDictionary(checkAddress, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

// Etc do stuff...

    }
```

In iOS 8.4 i am able to pass in 250 items, loop through and get a call back for each one.

But in iOS 9.0 with the same code it fails, giving me errors for all but about 40 items.

The error I get back is

Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2

I assume apple doesn't like me bulk geocoding ?

But why does it work in 8.4 and not now in 9.0

I guess I need to use mapQuest ?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 9 might be more restrictive about this statement in the documentation:

> Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many
>   requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to
>   fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error
>   object with the value kCLErrorNetwork to your completion handler.

Comment: Yeah, I found this as well. Massive spanner in the works of my app thats for sure. Time for mapQuest... and their odd JSON responses...