# How to deal with space value in text view and text field using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitextfield

I am developing an app using **Swift**. In my app, I am getting a value from a `UITextField` and a `UITextView` and sending that value as a parameter to a **JSON** API. I am able to send the value, but when I send the value with white space, my app crashes and shows error as null value. But I need to send the value with space also. For example, getting the full name or address.

**Code:**

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.something.com/cid="+MyCustId+"", parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).response { (req, res, data, error) -> Void in
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)

}
```

Here, `MyCustId` is the variable which is getting the value from `UITextField`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: characterSet.urlAllowed

Comment: For URLs, space is a special character and needs to be percent encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `spaces` with `%20` in the `URL` by the following method.

```
func addPercentageToUrl(urlString : String) -> String{

            return urlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        }


func makeService(){
let url = addPercentageToUrl(urlString : "https://www.something.com/cid="+MyCustId+"")
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).response { (req, res, data, error) -> Void in
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)

}
}
```

Please update you code like this.

Comment: can you elaborate please

Comment: It means that when you are adding spaces in your Url which is "https://www.something.com/cid="+MyCustId+"<Space>" this is not valid. When you try to add a space in Url then web browser automatically add %20 in place of spaces while programmatically you have to add %20 in places of spaces in the Url so that it successfully hit the server.

Comment: using that function how do i send that value as a parameter

Comment: I have updated my answer please try this way.

Comment: thanks.........man

Comment: Kindly up vote my answer too :)

Comment: am using swift 2.2..am getting error at that func addPercentageToUrl

Comment: try this one.
let urlwithPercentEscapes = myurlstring.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

Comment: the error is string has no member as addingpercenrencoding

Comment: Please read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064754/how-to-use-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwithallowedcharacters-for-a-url-in-swi

Answer (score 0):

please use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters method for adding space in url

```
let myStr = strOfUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()
```