# Swift: value of type has no member, cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm creating some functionality in my vacation app by following a tutorial on Ray Wenderlich, so I created this class:

```
import Foundation
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON

class GoogleDataProvider {
    var photoCache = [String:UIImage]()
    var placesTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    var session: URLSession {
        return NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    }

    func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, types:[String], completion: (([GooglePlace]) -> Void)) -> ()
    {
        var urlString = "http://localhost:10000/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true"
        let typesString = types.count > 0 ? types.joined(separator: "|") : "food"
        urlString += "&types=\(typesString)"
        urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

        if let task = placesTask, task.taskIdentifier > 0 && task.state == .Running {
            task.cancel()
        }

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {data, response, error in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            var placesArray = [GooglePlace]()
            if let aData = data {
                let json = JSON(data:aData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil)
                if let results = json["results"].arrayObject as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    for rawPlace in results {
                        let place = GooglePlace(dictionary: rawPlace, acceptedTypes: types)
                        placesArray.append(place)
                        if let reference = place.photoReference {
                            self.fetchPhotoFromReference(reference) { image in
                                place.photo = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completion(placesArray)
            }
        }
        placesTask?.resume()
    }


    func fetchPhotoFromReference(reference: String, completion: ((UIImage?) -> Void)) -> () {
        if let photo = photoCache[reference] as UIImage? {
            completion(photo)
        } else {
            let urlString = "http://localhost:10000/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=200&photoreference=\(reference)"
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            session.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {url, response, error in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                if let url = url {
                    let downloadedPhoto = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!)
                    self.photoCache[reference] = downloadedPhoto
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        completion(downloadedPhoto)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                }
                }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

But I got two errors.

For this line:

```
 urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

I got the error:

> Value of type `'String'` has no member `'stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters'`

and in this line:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

I got the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type `'UIApplication'`

I tried to look on the net to find a solution for these issues, but nothing. Can someone tell me how I can adjust these?

Comment: Searching stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters + Swift 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064754/how-to-use-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwithallowedcharacters-for-a-url-in-swi (else, the Swift 3 signature is in the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These function names changed with Swift 3. For the first one, you should use `String.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`:

```
urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Also, `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` became `UIApplication.shared` and `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` got an `is` prefix, similar to other boolean values in Swift 3:

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Comment: thank you it work! i only take this last issue : "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"   in this line  let downloadedPhoto = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!)

Comment: @bero The Swift 3 syntax for that would be `let downloadedPhoto = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))`