# Check if URL is valid in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

How can you check to see if a URL is valid in Swift 4? I'm building a simple web browser for personal use and even though I know to enter the full URL each time I'd rather get an alert instead of the app crashing if I forget.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var urlTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func startBrowser(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url = self.urlTextField.text {
            let sfViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
            self.present(sfViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        print ("Now browsing in SFSafariViewController")
    }
}
```

For example, if I was to type in a web address without http:// or https:// the app would crash with the error `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported.'`

Comment: You should use URLComponents to compose your url

Comment: @LeoDabus Would that be possible in my case?

Comment: Why not? You can create a custom initializer where the default scheme is http

Comment: Are you accepting more complex urls with query items on it?

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not sure as I've only tried simple URLs so far

Comment: What about urls with white spaces? Are you precent encoding it?

Comment: This will be more complex than you think

Comment: @LeoDabus Using `let urlString = url_text.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)` fixes the search function to allow spaces

Comment: You should use .urlQueryAllowed only in the query part of your string

Comment: @LeoDabus Which character set would be the best instead of `urlQueryAllowed`

Comment: As I said there is different set for each part of your url but you can create a custom set https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064937/2303865

Comment: if let url = URL(string: urlLink.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!) {
            ...PRESENT SAFARI HERE...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably crashing because you're using the `!` operator and not checking that it will work. Instead try:

```
@IBAction func startBrowser(_ sender: Any) {
    if let urlString = self.urlTextField.text {
        let url: URL?
        if urlString.hasPrefix("http://") {
            url = URL(string: urlString)
        } else {
            url = URL(string: "http://" + urlString)
        }
        if let url = url {
            let sfViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            self.present(sfViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print ("Now browsing in SFSafariViewController")
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you the idea of how to handle the different cases, but you probably want something more sophisticated which can deal with https and strips whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't word my question correctly. The app crashes every time I don't add http:// to the beginning so I was looking for a fix (Maybe an if/else statement?)

Comment: How about with the change I just made?

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed that. That's what I get for not trying to compile first.

Comment: You should add the details of the crash. Where exactly is it?

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing `URL(string: url_text) ??` from the code

Comment: That change means that you can't paste in a string that has `https://` at the start. I've added an explicit check for this.

Comment: This code wouldn't compile. What is `starts(with: "http://")` ? String method for that is called `hasPrefix`. And url is optional, checking it is not nil doesn't unwrap it. You should use `if let url = url {`

Comment: I don't know why I went with the `!= nil`. I always unwrap properly. I'll fix that. The `starts(with: "http://")` is valid Swift 4 but I should be using `hasPrefix`. Thanks.

Comment: @GaryMakin thats true `starts(with:)` Is a new sequence instance method available for Xcode 9 or later.

Comment: I've been doing too much snake_case programming at work lately. I definitely prefer camelCase. Fixed and gave it a better variable name.

Comment: Not saying that I would use it in production code but you could check if it hasPrefix "http" only this way it wouldn't add the scheme twice  if the string starts with https

Comment: @LeoDabus Given that `SFSafariViewController` can only handle http and https, that might be sufficient. But what if the web site was called httphelp.com? I think explicit tests for both would be better. I did try to cover this (in a hand-wavey way) in the last sentence in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the comments on the accepted answer, I could see that you actually want to validate the URL, to check if it's valid before trying to open with Safari to prevent any crash.

You can use regex to validate the string(I created an extension, so on any string, you can check if it is a valid URL):

```
extension String {
func validateUrl () -> Bool {
        let urlRegEx = "((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I implement this into my function?

Comment: func canOpenURL(_ string: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = string,
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            else { return false }
        
        if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) { return false }
        let regEx = "((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?"

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[regEx])
        return predicate.evaluate(with: string)
    }