# What is an easier way to replace multiple characters with other characters in a string in swift?

Tags: swift, character-replacement

I am currently trying to setup a string to be added to a HTTP POST request where a user would type text and tap '*enter*' and a request would be sent.

I know multiple characters (^,+,<,>) can be replaced with a single character ('_') like so:

```
userText.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^+<>]", with: "_"
```

I currently am using multiple functions of:

`.replacingOccurrences(of: StringProtocol, with:StringProtocol)`

like so:

```
let addAddress = userText.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_").replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "%2E").replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "%2D").replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "%28").replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "%29").replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "%2C").replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem you will run into with using addingPercentEncoding is that your question states that a space " " should be replaced with an underscore.  Using addingPercentEncoding for a space " " will return %20.  You should be able to combine some of these answers, define the remaining characters from your list that should return standard character replacement and get your desired outcome.

```
var userText = "This has.lots-of(symbols),&stuff"
userText = userText.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
let allowedCharacterSet = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".-(),&").inverted)
var newText = userText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet)

print(newText!) // Returns This_has%2Elots%2Dof%28symbols%29%2C%26stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is to manually encode the string with a percent encoding.

If that's the case, this will help you:

`addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`

> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all characters not in the specified set with percent-encoded characters.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding

For your specific case this should work:

`userText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally to use `.urlHostAllowed` CharacterSet since it works almost always.

```
textInput.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

But the best is combining all the possible options like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064937/5999975) which  will make sure you make it right.